# how not to auto increment id after realod fixture?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures, api-platform.com

I'm looking for a way to not increment the id after relaunching my Fixtures.

I explained, i made Fixtures, and when I run them the first time the id are for example between 1 and 6 ( its normal ) but when I decide to relaunch the fixtures the id are between 7 and 12. But me what i want its my id stay always between 1 and 6 because i made something in a code who will always need the same number of Id.

ps: my Fixtures are generate with Alice Bundle on Symfony 4 and Api-Platform.

So i tried to fix the Id in my fixtures case like this :

```
App\Entity\Camera:
    camera:
        id: 1
        parking: '@parking'
        type: big
    camera1:
        id: 2
        parking: '@parking'
        type: normal
    camera2:
        id: 3
        parking: '@parking'
        type: small
    camera3:
        id: 4
        parking: '@parking1'
        type: big
    camera4:
        id: 5
        parking: '@parking1'
        type: normal
    camera5:
        id: 6
        parking: '@parking1'
        type: small
```

And

```
App\Entity\Parking:
    parking:
        id: 1
        name: parking 1
    parking1:
        id: 2
        name: parking 2
```

and in the both Entity class i remove the "@ORM\GeneratedValue()" like :

```
/**
 * @Groups({"event"})
 * @ORM\Id()
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
```

but when i do that i have this error message :

```
  An error occurred while generating the fixture "parking" (App\Entity\Parking): Could not hydrate the property "id" of the object "parking" (class: App\Entity\Parking).  


In HydrationExceptionFactory.php line 85:

  Could not hydrate the property "id" of the object "parking" (class: App\Entity\Parking).  


In PropertyAccessor.php line 567:

  Could not determine access type for property "id" in class "App\Entity\Parking": Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "addId()"/"removeId()", "setId()", "id()", "__set()" or "__call()" exi  
  st and have public access in class "App\Entity\Parking".
```

can i have some help please?

**EDIT:** 
For exemple: I have a Json, and camera is a ManyToOne in a other Entity, when i do a post i need to add in the json "/cameras/id_of_camera", and i want all the id stay same for when i will do unittest or others.

```
{
    "label":"test",
    "camera": "/cameras/1",
}
```

Comment: Regardless of the answer to this, I strongly recommend _not_ writing application code that depends on specific autoincrement ids.

Comment: i dont realy understand

Comment: seems like in your fixtures you already can reference objects without a need to specify concrete ids, so why would you rely on concrete ids then? Also, a little pro tip: if you wanna run tests which require creating database records, do it in a transaction and then, at the end of the test, rollback (hope, I don't need to explain benefits of this approach much?).

Comment: i added the 'id' in my fixtures because i want i my database the id of fixtures how same, if i remove the "id" i added in the fixtures the code will work, but after i relaunch the fixtures the id will be incremented and its not what i want. I just edited my post to explain

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned this is not a good approach.

If you insist on doing it you will need to truncate the tables so they are reset, then when you add to the database the id will start from 1 again. So using the ORMPurge is probably the best way to do it.